# How to configure tesseract to recognize this number?

Tags: tesseract, digits

I would like tesseract to recognize numbers on the attached image:

[image: Number 81]

Tesseract is able to recognize when the number starts with 7, but once there is an 8, it fails.

I am using something like this:

```
tesseract image.png output --oem 3 --psm 11 -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789
```

I cycled through all options of oem and psm (1..20), but none was good. Am I missing something here to make it work?

Comment: What about reading [doc][1] before submitting a question to SO?

  [1]: https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdoc/blob/main/ImproveQuality.md#inverting-images

Answer (score 0):

I converted the image to b/w and inverted colors. Then tesseract started getting better results.